# Split Spark DataFrame in half without overlapping data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe with about `38313` number of rows, for some AB Testing use cases I need to split this DataFrame into half and store them separately.

for this purpose, I am using `org.apache.spark.sql.randomSplit`, this function seems works fine on a small dataset but when you have a big DataFrame it starts causing some issue. 
I have noticed that every time I split my DataFrame in half I get an overlapping result

```
val dedupTarget = target.dropDuplicates("identifier")

val splitDF = dedupTarget.randomSplit(Array(0.5, 0.5), 1000)

// splitDF(0) and splitDF(1) has some overlapping rows and some data we had in dedupTarget doesn't even exist in any of them
```

based on the randomSplit implementation

> ```
> // It is possible that the underlying dataframe doesn't guarantee the ordering of rows in its
> // constituent partitions each time a split is materialized which could result in
> // overlapping splits. To prevent this, we explicitly sort each input partition to make the
> // ordering deterministic.
> // MapType cannot be sorted.
> ```

So I tried to sort my DataFrame before the split but it didn't help at all.

```
val dedupTarget = target.dropDuplicates("identifier").orderBy(col("identifier").desc)

val splitDF = dedupTarget.randomSplit(Array(0.5, 0.5), 1000)
```

Comment: This means there might be a bug in the implementation of randomSplit. Thus, it would be smarter to provide a MVCE to support this claim and a bug ticket should be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you a different approach.

Get a sample containing half of the dataframe as the first dataframe:

```scala
val firstDF = dedupTarget.sample(false, 0.5)
```

And then subtract it from the initial DF as the second half:

```scala
val secondDF = dedupTarget.except(firstDF)
```

This way you get two dataframes without overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is, create a random column and use it to split your initial dataframe into two. If you need two equal parts (half), get the median (of myrandcol) and use the median in filter instead of 0.5 as in the following example.

```
scala> df.show
+---+----+
| id|data|
+---+----+
|  1|  10|
|  2|  20|
|  3|  30|
|  4|  40|
|  5|  50|
|  6|   5|
|  7|  15|
|  8|  25|
|  9|  35|
| 10|  45|
| 11|  55|
| 12|  65|
+---+----+


scala> val dfrand = df.withColumn("myrandcol", rand())
dfrand: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, data: int ... 1 more field]

scala> dfrand.show
+---+----+--------------------+
| id|data|           myrandcol|
+---+----+--------------------+
|  1|  10|0.032922537840013755|
|  2|  20|  0.3033357451409988|
|  3|  30|  0.3540969077830527|
|  4|  40|  0.3303614771224386|
|  5|  50| 0.43494868849484125|
|  6|   5|  0.4250309835092507|
|  7|  15|  0.7405114480878822|
|  8|  25|  0.7591141079555013|
|  9|  35|  0.7497022992064433|
| 10|  45| 0.27779407072568674|
| 11|  55|  0.8203602166103228|
| 12|  65|  0.9171256953932918|
+---+----+--------------------+

scala> val dfA = dfrand.where($"myrandcol" <= 0.5)
dfA: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: int, data: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val dfB = dfrand.where($"myrandcol" > 0.5)
dfB: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: int, data: int ... 1 more field]

scala> dfA.show
+---+----+--------------------+
| id|data|           myrandcol|
+---+----+--------------------+
|  1|  10|0.032922537840013755|
|  2|  20|  0.3033357451409988|
|  3|  30|  0.3540969077830527|
|  4|  40|  0.3303614771224386|
|  5|  50| 0.43494868849484125|
|  6|   5|  0.4250309835092507|
| 10|  45| 0.27779407072568674|
+---+----+--------------------+


scala> dfB.show
+---+----+------------------+
| id|data|         myrandcol|
+---+----+------------------+
|  7|  15|0.7405114480878822|
|  8|  25|0.7591141079555013|
|  9|  35|0.7497022992064433|
| 11|  55|0.8203602166103228|
| 12|  65|0.9171256953932918|
+---+----+------------------+
```